# Sharing a blog post on facebook showing wrong information

Tags: blogs

I'm trying to share a blog post on facebook. I originally didn't set a featured image, so it took a random one and now I can't get it to choose the featured image at all. I've cleared my blog cashe, the firefox cashe and even tried google chrome, and it still shows the wrong pic. I even went as far as to change the pic on my post, and it still shows the wrong pic.

Any ideas where the problem is and how do I clear it?
+

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. 
Facebook has it's own cashe so you can go to their debugger tool and see what it will produce.
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/
You can also get it to reload the information and be able to produce the required result